# How to configure embedded Jetty to pick up web fragments?

Tags: java, xml, spring, configuration, jetty

My Java app uses embedded Jetty 9.2.2. I added a library to pom.xml containg web_fragment.xml file. But the fragment is not picked up by Jetty. When I start the application I can see in logs that the library is loaded. However when a request is made to a servlet from the library, the app returns 404.
How to make it to work?

In the app there is a Spring configuration file dispatcher-servlet.xml and the library is included there:

```
<import resource="classpath:/web.fragment.lib.spring.xml" />
```

There is no web.xml file, but the app contains spring.xml file with mappings. It uses the dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd"
       default-lazy-init="false">

  <context:annotation-config/>
  <context:property-placeholder system-properties-mode="FALLBACK" location="classpath:config.properties"/>

  <bean name="WebServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server" init-method="start">
    <property name="connectors">
      <list>
        <bean name="LocalSocket" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
          <constructor-arg ref="WebServer"/>
          <property name="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
          <property name="port" value="${jetty.port}"/>
        </bean>
      </list>
    </property>

    <property name="handler">
      <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
        <property name="handlers">
          <list>
            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler">
              <property name="sessionHandler">
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler"/>
              </property>
              <property name="contextPath" value="${context.path}"/>
              <property name="servletHandler">
                <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
                  <property name="servlets">
                    <list>
                      <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder">
                        <property name="name" value="dispatcherServlet"/>
                        <property name="servlet">
                          <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet"/>
                        </property>
                        <property name="initParameters">
                          <map>
                            <entry key="contextConfigLocation" value="**classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml**"/>
                          </map>
                        </property>
                      </bean>
                    </list>
                  </property>
                  <property name="servletMappings">
                    <list>
                      <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping">
                        <property name="pathSpecs">
                          <list>
                            <value>/</value>
                          </list>
                        </property>
                        <property name="servletName" value="dispatcherServlet"/>
                      </bean>
                    </list>
                  </property>
                </bean>
              </property>
            </bean>
          </list>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web Fragment auto configuration is a feature of the WebAppContext's Configuration layers](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-webapps.html).

In your example, you are using neither.
You are using Jetty, in an embedded sense, and are building up the list of servlets manually.

You'll either have to switch to building up your application via a WebAppContext or manually have to add the features that those web fragments provide.

The important thing to understand, is that web fragments are fragments of the webapp descriptor, which is a complicated feature of a webapp, which is something that is tracked by the WebAppContext, which is something that is configured by the list of Configuration layers defined in that specific WebAppContext.

Comment: See also: https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-webapps.html